# Regex to extract UNC paths

Tags: regex, powershell, csv

Help to extract UNC paths from the list (UTF8 encoding): https://drive.google.com/file/d/1y2J0k851Dm-N9cPRB_75V-huDCvGtko-/
The regex finds some but is it possible to improving its hit rate? : https://regex101.com/r/1au08n/1

```
$x= Import-Csv .\measure_groups.csv -Encoding UTF8 -Delimiter "`t"
$unc_regex = '\\\\[\w\d.-]+\\([\w\d\s\&\(\).-]+\\)*[\w\d\s.-]+'    
$x | select  info, @{n = "UNC_raw"; e={($_.info | Select-String -Pattern $unc_regex).Matches.Value } } | fl
```

If there are more then one UTC paths in a single record no work needed.
[image]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Comment: What is actually the question ?

Comment: @Civette write a better regex? Mine is misses some UNC paths

Comment: Does [this](https://regex101.com/r/1au08n/2) works for you?

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi It's almost perfect thank you:), you saved people from monotonous work. One small remark, if you could do it, it would be great, if not that's OK. ";" - character do not related to UNC path. For example: "; Owner Update - INC000009094532" has nothing to do with UNC path.

Comment: That's very easy. Any character like `;` that you want to disallow from matching, just put it in the negation character set. Change this `[^\r\n>]` to this `[^\r\n;>]` and it will stop matching undesired text. Similarly if you later realize some other unwanted characters are getting matched, you can yourself update that character set and get the desired results. Here is the new [demo](https://regex101.com/r/1au08n/3) just like you wanted.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi & @user2978216 : Just be carefull as your solution is matching `read access to \\eursmz-hub21\Teams\Finance\CAPEX, except \\eursmz-hub21\Teams\Finance\CAPEX\limit` as one single UNC path, which is incorrect.

Comment: @PatrickJanser: Like I mentioned in above comment, just need to add `,` also in that negation character set or any such unwanted character which OP should be able to do himself now

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi Yes, I understand, but it's rather complicated as it's relatively common that some folder names contain a comma (It's typically the case in his example). I also see that this `, except` case is complicated to handle properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with something based on the characters which are not allowed
in a file or directory name. I would say this list:

- `\` and `/`
- `:` and `;`
- `*`, `"`, `?`
- `<`, `>` and `|`
- new lines (`\r` and `\n`)

This means that a directory name should be `[^\\\/:;*"?<>|\n\r]{1,254}`
as it should be at least one char and not more than 254 chars.

Now, the full path starts with a double backslash and is then followed
by folders separated by a backslash. But on some of your lines, we can
have two paths, so we could say that we are looking for:

1. A backslash.
2. A backslash followed by a directory name, one or several times.
3. An optional terminating backslash, but not if it is followed by
   another backslash (because this would be a new path).

This leads to this regex:

```
/\\(?:\\[^\\\/:;*"?<>|\n\r]{1,254})+\\?(?!\\)/gu
```

- The `g` pattern flag is for **g**lobal (match all of them).
- The `u` pattern flag is for **u**nicode, just to be sure it will work
  with special characters in other languages. I can't tell you if emoji
  characters are allowed in filenames or not, so maybe the pattern for
  a folder name isn't totally correct.

You can test it here: https://regex101.com/r/VzwIre/1

**A little problem with these input lines:**

```
read access to \\eursmz-hub21\Teams\Finance\CAPEX, except \\eursmz-hub21\Teams\Finance\CAPEX\limit
Access to folders from \\eursmz-hub21\Teams\FRP\Finance\Actual vs Plan 2008\06\WD1 till \\eursmz-hub21\Teams\FRP\Finance\Actual vs Plan 2008\12\WD1
```

As you mentionned, it has 2 UCN paths. The regular expression
I proposed is able to match both items instead of one, but is
not able to not match the `, except` or `till` parts, wich
have nothing to do in both paths. And in your case, I don't
know if the second path should be in your concern of capturing
it or not.

Unfortunately the logs are not easy to read because of the
missing quotes around the paths.

Ideas of solutions:

- Clean up all paths finishing by `, except` by searching for
  `,\s*except$` and replacing it by nothing. Same problem with
  the `till` in the second example I found in your CSV. I'm
  sure they are other surprises to come...
- Try to add negative lookahead rules in the regular
  expression, but this seems to be relatively complicated (I
  already had several tries without success).
- Capture lines with two paths separatly with another regex
  first and get it out of your input for the second search.
- If you can change the config of the log output to the CSV
  file, then I would try to delimit all paths with a double
  quote. As paths can be made of spaces, it's really complicated
  to get a full working regular expression.